# Is DNSSEC immune to stripping signatures?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, dns, dns-spoofing, dnssec

In my opinion, it should be possible to forge DNS reply so it doesn't include DS/RRSIG/... parts for any request, thus bypassing DNSSEC validation of resolved domain.

Is DNSSEC system immune to this kind of attack?
Does Unbound with locally stored DLV and ROOT anchor files make any difference?

Comment: Don't have time to write a full answer - but yes, DNSSEC is immune, as long as you have DLV or root anchors. Non-existence of security on a delegation is also signed. Keyword: DS, NSEC, type bitmap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, DNSSEC is immune to this kind of attack. Starting at an anchor (usually the root, sometimes DLV), every delegation is either explicitly secure (presence of DS set on delegation):

```
powerdns.com.       172800  IN  NS  powerdnssec1.ds9a.nl.
powerdns.com.       172800  IN  NS  powerdnssec2.ds9a.nl.
powerdns.com.       86400   IN  DS  44030 8 3 7DD75AE1565051F9563CF8DF976AC99CDCA51E3463019C81BD2BB083 82F3854E
powerdns.com.       86400   IN  DS  44030 8 2 D4C3D5552B8679FAEEBC317E5F048B614B2E5F607DC57F1553182D49 AB2179F7
powerdns.com.       86400   IN  DS  44030 8 1 B763646757DF621DD1204AD3BFA0675B49BE3279
```

or explicitly insecure (NSEC[3] bitmap proves absence of DS on delegation):

```
gov-1l.us.      7200    IN  NS  HNS1.BEYONDHOSTING.NET.
gov-1l.us.      7200    IN  NS  HNS2.BEYONDHOSTING.NET.
gov-1l.us.      86400   IN  NSEC    GOV-ABUSE.us. NS RRSIG NSEC
```

or implicitly insecure (NSEC3 opt-out):

```
stackexchange.com.  172800  IN  NS  brad.ns.cloudflare.com.
stackexchange.com.  172800  IN  NS  roxy.ns.cloudflare.com.
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - CK0QFMDQRCSRU0651QLVA1JQB21IF7UR NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM
4OTDAP6T1E8VS8BHMCK8CDHSGE3GCOBM.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - 4OTJJUP7OGM6C149HPOE7O9M1L9LS1OP NS DS RRSIG
```

(`stackexchange.com` hashes to `4otjehvpu9q5tm1d5v0ec302rcbll9um` which is covered by the second denial, thus there is no secure delegation).

In all of these cases, IF there is a secure delegation, the NSEC[3] record for the name in question will prove the presence of DS. Thus, if signatures are stripped, a validating client can detect this.

For further reading, I highly recommend [RFC7129: Authenticated Denial of Existence in the DNS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7129) and [section 5.2 (Authenticating Referrals) of RFC4035 (Protocol Modifications for the DNS Security Extensions)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4035#section-5.2)